# OG Tags Dinamicos MySQL y PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

Necesito ayuda con el siguiente problema ya que no he logrado encontrar la solución (creo que podría ser muy simple)
Tengo un página web en la cuál quiero usar OG Tags de forma dinamica (llenarlos dependiendo de la información en la base de datos). Todo funciona bien si agrego toda la información de conexión en la página donde tengo los tags peeeeero si uso las funciones de require o include (con el objetivo de separar los datos de conexión, recibo el siguiente mensaje de error en el Depurador de contenido compartido de Facebook "Your page has meta tags in the body instead of the head. This may be because your HTML was malformed and they fell lower in the parse tree."

Saben si puedo llenarlos de forma dinamica sin agregar toda la información de conexión en la misma página?

Gracias!

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: para que tengas mejor aceptación en el sitio, toma tu tiempo para copiar y pegar el código, así nosotros con mucho gusto trataremos de reproducir tu escenario y ayudarte con la respuesta. Por cierto, bienvenido al sitio, revisa https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 0):

tu pregunta no tiene que ver con los open graph tags, sino con un error de php. Me parece que estas teniendo un problema cuando incluis el archivo. En facebook linter podes ver el cuerpo entero de la pagina parseada, ahi fijate que pasa caundo queres incluir conexion.php, seguro te sale un warning o un error que esta "rompiendo" el header. Acordate de no hacer ningun echo ni nada en el archivo "conexion.php" tampoco. si incluis el link a la pagina en el servidor va a ser mas facil ayudarte.

Answer (score 0):

Puede ser porque la Data que se muestra debe ser primero que la conexión, el tiempo en que se realiza la petición y se llenan los datos para enviar. Es decir, los datos deben de estar llegando a Facebook sin llenarse.

Lo que a mi me funciona es instanciar un método que de acuerdo a la ruta trae datos de lo que se quiere mostrar

```
$ogData = templateController::ctrGetData($route);
```

con eso ya cuando se pasan los datos a los meta tags ya vienen llenos

```
<meta property="og:title"   content="<?php echo $ogData['title'];?>">

<meta property="og:url" content="<?php echo $ogData['route'];?>">

<meta property="og:description" content="<?php echo $ogData['description'];?>">

<meta property="og:image"  content="<?php echo $ogData['image'];?>">

<meta property="og:type"  content="website">
```